# Ist der Genitiv manchmal ein Ersatz für "über" etwas?

Tags: meaning, grammatical-case, genitive

Dieser Satz erscheint in "Dem Eisenbahnunglück" von Thomas Mann:

> Da ward mir leicht, und ich mischte mich unter die Leute, die standen
> und schwatzten und sich anfreundeten gelegentlich **ihres Mißgeschickes**
> und aufschnitten und sich wichtig machten.

Was ist die Funktion von "ihres Mißgeschickes" in diesem Satz? Das Verb "sich anfreunden" fordert kein Genitivobjekt, sofern ich recherchiert habe. Google Translate ergibt "about their misfortunes," was mir andeutet, dass in diesem Fall der Genitiv eine Bedeutung wie "über ihr Mißgeschick" hat. Stimmt das überhaupt? Wenn ja, nur in diesem besonderen Fall, oder ist der Genitiv im Allgemeinen so ein Ersatz für "über" etwas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"[an]gelegentlich + Genitiv" ist eine (etwas aus der Mode gekommene) Wendung, die soviel wie "bei der Gelegenheit" bedeutet.

Zum Beispiel:

> Wir trafen einander gelegentlich des Unfalls.

Bedeutet soviel wie: wir waren in einen Unfall verwickelt (oder vielleicht auch nur Zeugen) und dabei - bei der Gelegenheit - haben wir einander getroffen.

Die Bedeutung des Satzteils ist also eine Beschreibung der "Leute", die nämlich standen und schwatzten und sich anfreundeten, weil sie gemeinsam ein Mißgeschick - vermutlich das Eisenbahnunglück aus dem Titel - erlitten haben, außerdem haben sie noch aufgeschnitten und sich wichtig gemacht.

Comment: Danke, es kam mir nicht mal in den Sinn, "gelegentlich" nachzuschlagen!

Answer (score 3):

Der relevante Teil ist "gelegentlich ihres Mißgeschickes", das Missgeschick ist die Gelegenheit für die Gespräche und das Anfreunden.

Comment: Ja, meine Antwort ist weniger ausführlich und kam erst nach der anderen. Ich konnte sie erst später abschicken, weil ich die Internetverbindung verloren hatte.

Comment: Verdammte Internetverbindung - danke!